# Hidden grading on $kS_n$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups, hecke-algebras

[Brundan and Kleshchev](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00222-009-0204-8) showed that if $k$ is a field of characteristic $p$, then the group ring $kS_n$ of the symmetric group $S_n$ admits an integer grading which is nontrivial in the sense that it is not concentrated in degree 0.  This grading is explicit, in the sense that Brundan-Kleshchev give an explicit isomorphism of $kS_n$ with a specific graded ring.  However, on the occasions that I've tried to work out examples of this grading by tracing through the isomorphism, I have found it extremely hard going.  (Caveat: I am definitely an amateur at this!)

> **Question 1:** Are examples of the Brundan-Kleshchev grading worked out anywhere?

In the above question I *think* I am looking for particular choices of $n$ or $p$ or both, where the gradings of specific elements of $kS_n$ are written out.

> **Question 2:** Are there any alternative ways to describe or compute the Brundan-Kleshchev grading on $kS_n$?

(n.b. Brundan and Kleshchev give gradings on a more general family of algebras than just $kS_n$ for $\mathrm{char}(k)=p$, but I am just asking about this special case.)

Comment: "non-trivial grading" in what? Usually "non-trivial" means the grading is not concentrated in degree zero. An obvious non-grading of $kG$ is precisely graded by $G$, and hence also by the abelian quotient of $G$ $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$— you would certainly not call this "hidden". Do you mean in $\mathbf{Z}$ (or a torsion-free abelian group)?

Comment: @YCor The hidden grading is an integer grading, nontrivial meaning that it’s not concentrated in degree 0.

Comment: Is $p$ assumed to be $\le n$? if it's true for arbitrary large $p$ and fixed $n$, I'd guess it's also true in characteristic zero.

Comment: @YCor: There is no assumption relating $n$ and $p$, and the result also holds in characteristic 0.

Comment: For anyone confused by this, it seems that semisimple algebras like matrix algebras can have nontrivial gradings - we can grade the algebra of $n \times n$ matrices so that matrices with unique nonvanishing entry in row $i$ and column $j$ have grade $i-j$. But probably these are more interesting once we have $p\leq n$.